Properties of $L(s, \chi)$ for primitive/non-primitive $\chi$
Let $q$ be an integer $\geq 2$ and $\chi$ a primitive character mod $q$. Using Theorem 4.3.6 and Lemma 4.3.1, prove the following:
a) $L(s, \chi)$ has an analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$.
b) If $\chi$ is even, then $L(s, \chi)$ has simple zeros at $s = -2, -4, \dots$ and $L(s, \chi) \neq 0$ if $\text{Re}(s) < 0$, $s \notin \{-2, -4, \dots\}$.
If $\chi$ is odd, then $L(s, \chi)$ has simple zeros at $s = -1, -3, -5, \dots$ and $L(s, \chi) \neq 0$ if $\text{Re}(s) < 0$, $s \notin \{-1, -3, -5, \dots\}$.
What about $s = 0$?
c) Prove (a) and (b) if $\chi$ is non-principal, but not necessarily primitive. What about $s = 0$?
My try:
For part a I used a theorem that says that $1/\Gamma$ is analytic in all of $\mathbb C$
from which the conclusion is immediate.
In part b, I can write from theorem 4.3.6 $L(s,\chi)=\xi(s,\chi)(\frac{q}{\pi})^{-s/2}\frac{1}{\Gamma (s/2)}$
I know that $\Gamma (s/2)$ has simple poles at $s/2=0,-1,-2,...$ ie at $s=0,-2,-4,...$ which trasnform into simple zeros of $1/\Gamma (s/2)$, outside those values I know $\Gamma (s/2)$ is not zero. If I can prove that $\epsilon(s,\chi)$ is not zero for Re$(s)<0$and s not in $\{-2,-4\}$ etc I would be done.  I think I have to use the equation $\xi(1-s,\bar\chi)=c(\chi)\xi(s,\chi)$ , but I can't figure out how.
My ideas are: If $s$ has $Res<0$, and I plug it on the RHS of the equation, it means that on the left hand side I get $\xi$ with at $s'=1-s >0$, and what do we know about $\xi(s', \chi)$ for $s'>0$ ? I wish we know it is positive, also how do I deal whith the character that has been conjugated? and should I bother looking into $c(\chi)$?
Also I don't know why $0$ has to be excluded from the simple zeros
1 How do i finish this?
2 I have no idea how to procede with part c, I find characters very difficult to deal with. How do I go about solving it?
reference lecture notes: https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertsejh/ant20-4.pdf




What you did is indeed correct, we have $L(s,\chi)=\left(\frac{q}{\pi}\right)^{-s/2}\frac{\xi(s,\chi)}{\Gamma (s/2)}$ or $L(s,\chi)=\left(\frac{q}{\pi}\right)^{-(s+1)/2}\frac{\xi(s,\chi)}{\Gamma ((s+1)/2)}$. For the right hand side, all of the factors are entire hence so is $L(s,\chi)$.

b) First let $\chi$ be even, from the identity $L(s,\chi)=\left(\frac{q}{\pi}\right)^{-s/2}\frac{\xi(s,\chi)}{\Gamma (s/2)}$, the function $L(s,\chi)$ has simple zeros at $-2\mathbb Z^+$ because $\Gamma(s/2)$ has poles at these points. To describe the behavior at $s=0$ and $\text{Re}(s)<0$, we use the functional equation of $\xi$. By Theorem 4.3.6, we get
$$\xi(1-s,\overline{\chi})=c_\chi \xi(s,\chi)\Longrightarrow \left( \frac{q}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{1-s}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{1-s}{2} \right)L(1-s,\overline{\chi})=c_\chi \left( \frac{q}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{s}{2} \right)L(s,\chi).$$
If $s=0$, then the left hand side equals $\sqrt{\frac{q}{\pi}}\Gamma(1/2)L(1,\overline{\chi})$. By the well-known theorem, $L(1,\overline{\chi})\neq0$. Thus the left hand side is non-zero, while the right hand side equals $c_\chi\Gamma\left( \frac{s}{2} \right)L(s,\chi)\big\rvert_{s=0}$. But $\Gamma\left( \frac{s}{2} \right)$ has a simple pole at $0$, thus in order of this to be finite non-zero we need $L(s,\chi)$ to have a simple zero at $s=0$. If $\text{Re}(s)<0$ and $s\notin-2\mathbb Z^+$. We again use the functional equation. Since $\text{Re}(1-s)>1$, the left hand side makes sense and is non-zero, (the $L$ function does not have zeros in the region $\sigma>1$ because of the Euler product). Now $c_\chi \left( \frac{q}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{s}{2} \right)$ makes sense because $s\notin -2\mathbb Z^+$. Therefore $L(s,\chi)$ is non-zero because the left hand side also is. We obtain the second part with the similar analysis for $\chi$ odd. Analogous to the poles of $\Gamma\left( \frac{s}{2} \right)$, we have $L(s,\chi)$ has simple zeroes at $1-2\mathbb Z^+$, is non-zero at $s=0$ and $\text{Re}(s)<0, s\notin1-2\mathbb Z^+$. These come from the poles of $\Gamma\left( \frac{1-s}{2} \right)$.
c) Since we have already solved the problem for primitive characters, we seek to reduce the problem to primitive characters. If $\chi$ is non-primitive and has the conductor $d$, then there exists a primitive $\mod d$ character $\psi$ such that $\chi=\psi\chi_0$ where $\chi_0$ is the principle character $\mod q$. Directly substituting this into the Euler product, we obtain
$$L(s,\chi)=L(s,\psi)\prod_{p|q}1-\frac{\psi(p)}{p^s}.$$
The rest is easy since $\psi$ is primitive. You can look at Apostol's analytic number theory book for proofs of all of the facts i have used here.
Also i think you should remove the abstract algebra tag.

Thank you for your answer, Could you please elavorate on the "the rest" at the end of your answer, I would like to verify my answers, plus there are somethings I am not so sure about.

for the discussion on b to be complete, don't I need to know if $\xi(s,\chi)$ has no zeros?

I mean the zeros of $ L(s,\chi)$ come from the zeros of $1/\Gamma$, $\xi$ shouldn't introduce other zeros. However, I am reading that $\xi $has trivial zeros, which corresponds to those of $L(s,\chi),$ I am confused, the zeros belong to $1/\Gamma$ noot to $\xi $

Since we already classified all zeros of $L(s,\psi)$, we only look at the factor $\prod_{p|q}1-\frac{\psi(p)}{p^s}$. Thus only additional zeros come from $s$ such that $p^s=\psi(p)$ for some $p|q$, counted according to their multiplicities. Since $|\psi(p)|=1$, (it would be impossible for it to be $0$), we must have $\text{Re}(s)=0$. Note that multiplicities may stack.

For part c, how do we know if such conductor exists?

We assumed that $\chi$ is not primitive, thus it has a conductor that is  not $q$. (Definition of a primitive character is a character such that the conductor equals $q$.)

Could you indicate what I have to do to check the rest of part c once I have this $\psi$ that is primitive? And how do handle the $s=0$ case?

I also having a lor of difficulty with the euler product, how does it gets that form, and how do I know that it is not the factors are not zero

I think you should have a look at Apostol's Introduction To Analytic Number Theory. It explains all of these concepts in great detail and includes their proofs. Theorem 12.9 is the Euler product lemma i mentioned. Look at theorem 8.17 and 8.18 for the equation $\chi=\psi\chi_0$.

I managed to arrive to your expression

The question is, this product is just analytic on Re s >1, so how can I deal with this to prove part a? If this was entire, I would be reduced to the previous case

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
